Entering text box on iPad goes into “find in page” mode in Firefox/Safari
I’m using an iPad Pro with face ID, with the Apple external keyboard, and a logi mouse.
Using Firefox or Safari, whenever I go into a text input box (like for editing this question, or using Whatsapp), the browser goes into the “search for text within the page” mode, letting me search up or down. It’s quite annoying, because the bar that does that often obscures where I’m trying to write.
How can I stop this happening?
When I searched for this problem with Firefox, a solution suggested off turning an automatic “type to search” mode, but there doesn’t seem to be an “about:preferences” page in Firefox on iPad.
Is there anything I can do?
EDIT
To be more specific about what happens:
In Firefox, it looks like this:

The arrows in the bottom bar move between text fields. The arrows in the top bar don’t seem to do anything useful, but just lose focus. Clicking “done” leaves the text field.
In Safari, it looks like this:


Do you want to hide this bar altogether? Because the functionality of these arrows are not to search within the page, they just allow you to focus on the different text fields in the page (similar to tab).

In Firefox, the top bar does not have that functionality. Yes, I would like to hide any/all bars.
